# Web login using python3 requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to web scrape the a piece of news. I try to login into the website by python so that I can have full access to the whole web page. But I have looked at so many tutorials but still fail.
Here is the code. Can anyone tell me why.
There is no bug in my code. But I still can not see the full text, which means I am still not log in.

`

```
url='https://id.wsj.com/access/pages/wsj/us/signin.html?mg=id-wsj&mg=id-wsj'
payload={'username':'my_user_name',
         'password':'******'}
session=requests.Session()
session.get(url)
response=session.post(url,data=payload)
print(response.cookies)
r=requests.get('https://www.wsj.com/articles/companies-push-to-repeal-amt-after-senates-last-minute-move-to-keep-it-alive-1512435711')
print(r.text)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your last **GET** request using the `response` variable. After all, it's the one who made the login and holds the cookies (if there are any). You've used a new `requests` object for your last request thus ignoring the login you just made.

Comment: i change "r=request.get(...)" to "session.get(...)" but the get method keeps running and can never reach to the print statement.